# Is there a command to find a character in a string in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

i.e. If we think of an input string in terms of an array, with string[0] being the first element and string[99] being the last.

Is there a way to read each individual character, or read a character in a certain position?

i.e. Let my string be "abcdefg".

How do I access the character 'd' so I can compare it with the characters around it? (Assuming I have already accessed those characters too)

Answer (score 1):

You go through the characters one by one (normally in a loop):

```
Load index value zero to r1
load maximum character count to r2
load searched character to r3

loop:
  compare r3 and string(r1) # this loads one character: lb  $t4, string($t1)
  if equal. branch to found
  decrement r2
  if equal. branch to not_found
  increment r1
  goto loop
```